# Debugging auto-deletion

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a script mostly built from other posts here that automatically deletes documents older than an hour. It's set to run every 12 hours but I've noticed that the last day it has not been catching the files to delete them, there are documents from 2/19 that should have been deleted still in my folder. I am looking for help to get the script running again

Here is my script

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var fileIDs = [];

  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1*1*1;
  var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1wEOKcLO4O1viIMDGRrPd7eNOV3eo3vK3');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
    Logger.log('ID: ' + file.getId() + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
  }
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove the files before 1 hour from the current time by checking the last modified date.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");` is used. In this case, when today is February 19, 2024, `2024-02-19` is returned for various times. This is used by the search query of `'modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"'`. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- Also, in your script, `var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1*1*1;` is used. `new Date().getTime()` returns miliseconds. So, in this case, it is required to be `var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600 * 1000;`. I guessed that this might be the 2nd issue.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var fileIDs = [];

  // --- I modified the below script.
  var oldDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 3600 * 1000);
  var cutOffDate = oldDate.toISOString();
  // ---

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1wEOKcLO4O1viIMDGRrPd7eNOV3eo3vK3');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
    Logger.log('ID: ' + file.getId() + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
  }
  return fileIDs;
}

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function (fileID) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true);
  });
}
```

- When the function `deleteFiles` is run, the files before 1 hour from the current time are removed with `DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true)`. In this case, the files are put into the trash box.

#### References:

- [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)
- [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.  You will need to enable Drive API

```
function getOldFiles() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dth = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),dt.getHours() - 1);
  const cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(dth,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd")
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
    Logger.log('ID: ' + file.getId() + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
  }
}
```

I would probably avoid using the search and use the lastUpdated date

```
function getOldFiles() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dth = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), dt.getHours() - 1).valueOf()
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getLastUpdated().valueOf() < dth) {
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

You don't have to go through trash this way.  They are gone now.